# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined when returning a decrement value

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a reducer function that decrements a like value,

`console.log(myLikes.length - 1 )` gives me 0 and i want to output that to the component, but im getting an error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

This is happening on

`DISLIKE_POST_SUCCESS`

What should i do to return the value to the component

here is the **reducer**.

```
import {
  UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS,
  POST_COMMENT_SUCCESS,
  DELETE_IMAGE_FAILURE,
  FETCH_IMAGES_SUCCESS,
  DISLIKE_POST_SUCCESS,
  POST_COMMENT,
  POST_LIKE,
  POST_LIKE_SUCCESS,
  POST_LIKE_FAILURE,
  DELETE_IMAGE_SUCCESS,
} from '../actions/types';
const initialState = {
  images: [],
  likedByuser: false,
};
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_IMAGES_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        images: action.images,
      };
    case UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
      const newImage = action.data;
      return {
        images: [
          {
            id: newImage[0].id,
            user: {
              username: newImage[0].user.username,
            },
            comments: {
              comment_body: newImage[0].comments.comment_body,
            },
            image_title: newImage[0].image_title,
            img_url: newImage[0].img_url,
          },
          ...state.images, // pass the previous images,
        ],
      };
    case DELETE_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
      // console.log(action)
      return {
        ...state,
        images: state.images.filter(img => img.id !== action.data),
      };
    case DELETE_IMAGE_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.error,
      };
    case POST_LIKE:
      console.log(action);
      return {
        ...state,
      };
    case POST_LIKE_SUCCESS:
      console.log(action.data);
      const newState = { ...state }; // here I am trying to shallow  copy the existing state;
      const existingLikesOfPost = newState.images.find(image => image.id === action.data).likes;
      console.log(existingLikesOfPost)
      newState.images.find(image => image.id === action.data).likes = [...existingLikesOfPost, action.newLikeObject]; // using this approach I got some code duplication so I suggested the first approach of using **push** method of array.
      return newState;
    case DISLIKE_POST_SUCCESS:
      const likeState = { ...state.images[0].likes.length - 1 }; // here I am trying to shallow  copy the existing state;
      return likeState

    case POST_COMMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
      };
    case POST_COMMENT_SUCCESS:
      //  adds a comment to a post without having to re render.
      // console.log(action.data.commentBody);
      return {
        ...state,
        images: state.images.map((image) => {
          // appends new comment withing images redux state. only if image.id === action.id
          if (image.id === action.id) {
            return {
              ...image,
              comments: [
                ...image.comments,
                {
                  comment_body: action.data[0].comment_body,
                  user: {
                    username: action.data[0].user.username,
                  },
                },
              ],
            };
          }
          return image;
        }),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and here is where im calling the count value on

**image container (component)**

```
      .......
      return (
        <Grid item sm={12} md={12} className={classes.imageGridItem}>
              .......
              {img.likes ? img.likes.length  : null}
          .......
        </Grid>
      );
    }
}
ImageContainer.propTypes = {
  postComment: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  postLike: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
export default ImageContainer;
```

**Action.js**

```
export const dislikePostSuccess = (id, data) => ({
  type: DISLIKE_POST_SUCCESS,
  id,
  data
})
```

**Redux Saga**

```
export function* postLike(action) {
  try {
    const id = yield call(api.images.likePost, action.data.id);

    // yield put(postLikeSuccess(id, action.data.id));
    yield put(dislikePostSuccess(id, action.data.id))
  } catch (err) {
     console.log(err); 
  }
}
```

refactored DISLIKE_POST Case

```
case DISLIKE_POST_SUCCESS:
    return {
      ...state,
      images: state.images.map((image) => {
        // appends new comment withing images redux state. only if image.id === action.id
        if (image.id === action.data) {
          return {
            ...image,
            likes:[
              ...image.likes,
              image.likes.length - 1 // adds rather than subtract

            ]
          };
        }
        return image;
      }),
    };
```

raw data structure

```
{
  "id": 154,
  "image_title": "iiisdd",
  "img_url": "*********",
  "created_at": "2019-07-18T19:44:49.805Z",
  "updated_at": "2019-07-18T19:44:49.805Z",
  "user_id": 1,
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "googleId": null,
    "username": "*******,
    "password": "$********",
    "email": "e*******",
    "created_at": "2019-06-23T18:57:17.253Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-23T18:57:17.253Z"
  },
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": 51,
      "comment_body": "owls life",
      "created_at": "2019-07-18T20:04:51.484Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-07-18T20:04:51.484Z",
      "user_id": 8,
      "image_id": 154,
      "user": {
        "id": 8,
        "googleId": null,
        "username": "guest",
        "password": "********u",
        "email": "*******m",
        "created_at": "2019-07-18T20:04:34.315Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-07-18T20:04:34.315Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 52,
      "comment_body": "dadad",
      "created_at": "2019-07-19T20:16:40.103Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-07-19T20:16:40.103Z",
      "user_id": 1,
      "image_id": 154,
      "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "googleId": null,
        "username": "*******",
        "password": "*********",
        "email": "el***********",
        "created_at": "2019-06-23T18:57:17.253Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-06-23T18:57:17.253Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 53,
      "comment_body": "test",
      "created_at": "2019-07-21T22:12:44.729Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-07-21T22:12:44.729Z",
      "user_id": 1,
      "image_id": 154,
      "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "googleId": null,
        "username": "********",
        "password": "*********",
        "email": "el********",
        "created_at": "2019-06-23T18:57:17.253Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-06-23T18:57:17.253Z"
      }
    }
  ],
  "likes": [
    {
      "id": 24,
      "user_id": 2,
      "image_id": 154,
      "created_at": "2019-07-22T19:26:27.034Z",
      "deleted_at": "2019-07-22T19:26:27.034Z",
      "restored_at": "2019-07-22T19:26:27.034Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-07-22T19:26:27.034Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 141,
      "user_id": 1,
      "image_id": 154,
      "created_at": "2019-07-23T19:57:08.178Z",
      "deleted_at": "2019-07-23T19:57:08.178Z",
      "restored_at": "2019-07-23T19:57:08.178Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-07-23T19:57:08.178Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: what is the point of `newState.images.find`? you arent assigning it to anything

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is you aren't returning a state object inside `DISLIKE_POST_SUCCESS` aka where you `return myLikes.length - 1` . Which essentially mutates the current state to be a number.

Instead you should return a state copy like you are in the other case.

```
case DISLIKE_POST_SUCCESS:
  const likeState = { ...state }; // here I am trying to shallow  copy the existing state;
  //... code here
  return likeState
```

if you want to keep track of the count of likes, you can do that in an individual key that you append to the state object.

### Edit

When a user unlikes an image, you should pass both the like id and the image id, so you know which like to remove. I'd do something kinda like this (untested so please debug / validate).

```
case DISLIKE_POST_SUCCESS:
  const { imageIdToChange, likeIdToChange } = action.payload
  const images = [...state.images]; 
  const imageIdx = images.findIndex( (img) => img.id === imageIdToChange)
  if (imageIdx === -1) return state

  const likeIdx = images[imageIdx].likes.findIndex( like => like.id === likeIdToChange)
  if (likeIdx === -1) return state

  const imageToMutate = {...images[imageIdx]}
  imageToMutate.likes.splice(likeIdx, 1)
  images[imageIdx] = imageToMutate
  return {
    ...state,
    images: [...images]
  }
```

Comment: so   `return myLikes.length - 1`
      `return likeState;`

Comment: i need the `myLikes.length - 1` logic .

Comment: John could you edit the answer that would accommodate the myLikes.length - 1 logic

Comment: Ok, well how do you want to track that? as a state property? It looks like the likes are on your image itself?

Comment: how would i iterate the likeCount if its outside the nested object ? outside of the images initial state. Ill share my full reducer code. here is an idea on how im passing the data to the components, and everything else 
https://github.com/EliHood/ReactExpressPhotoShareApp/tree/master/client/src/reducers

Comment: I dont know what the data type is, thats what im asking. Is the like count on the images? you just then adjust the like count on that object itself.

Comment: im sorta confused John, could you provide a more effecient way to do this, given the github code flow and the reducer code. I might have to refactor all my code to accommodate the changes.

Comment: What is inside action for dislike? So, ok, you have an array of images. on the image you have a like count correct? You just need to find the index of that image object, adjust the count to be -1 then return the whole state again with the adjusted image object value.

Comment: John can you please update the code to better explain your comment. thx  :)

Comment: Do what you do in `POST_COMMENT_SUCCESS`. Just change the like count instead of comments. I dont want to just write the whole answer for you because I want you to understand the concepts themselves. Your reducer should be returning a whole state object, if you need to change an item in the state then change that item but return the whole state

Comment: dont `return image - 1;` instead just `return image;` at the end. do the `-1` on the `...image.likes` to subtract a count for the current image you are trying to change.

Comment: i made an update, let me know if im going in the right direction

Comment: can you just post a raw image object so I can know what the data type is? is `likes` an array?